# AngularJS multi-step form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

I've followed [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router) about **AngularJS Multi-Step Form Using UI Router**. The form works and I can save my data but now I'm having questions about how to validate each step in the form.

I have the following form with input fields:

**Step 1**

> - License Plate

**Step 2**

> - Name
> - Street
> - Zipcode
> - City
> - Email
> - Telephone

**Step 3**

> - Choose a date & time from a calendar

It looks somewhat like this:

[image]

I have a general base view like this:

```
<body ng-app="formApp">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- views will be injected here -->
        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

In my app.js I have the following (not complete, left the non important things out):

```
// app.js
// create our angular app and inject ngAnimate and ui-router
// =============================================================================
angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.calendar'])

// configuring our routes
// =============================================================================
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be /form/interests
        .state('form.license', {
            url: '/license',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-license.html'
        })

        // url will be nested (/form/profile)
        .state('form.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-profile.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/payment
        .state('form.appointment', {
            url: '/appointment',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-appointment.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/success
        .state('form.success', {
            url: '/success',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-success.html'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/license');
})

// our controller for the form
// =============================================================================
.controller('formController', function($scope, $http, $compile, $location, uiCalendarConfig) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.profile = {};


    $scope.next = function(step){

        if(step == 1) 
        {

        }
        else if(step == 2)
        {

        }
    };

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function(isValid) {

    };

});
```

My general form.html:

```
<!-- form.html -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

        <div id="form-container">
            <form id="appointment-form" name="appointmentform" ng-submit="processForm(appointmentform.$valid)">

                <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first step in my form is in form-license.html:

```
<!-- form-license.html -->
<label>Nummerplaat ingeven</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="license" ng-model="formData.license">

    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
        <a ng-click="next(1)" ui-sref="form.profile" class="btn btn-next btn-block">
            Volgende
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I'm wondering how I can validate this when they click on next button ... . It's not working with the normal required attribute.

Can somebody help me with this?

**UPDATE:**

Now I have in my first step the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
    <a ng-click="next(1, processForm)" ui-sref="form.profile" ng-disabled="!licenseValidated" class="btn btn-next btn-block">
        Volgende
    </a>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
var validateLicense = function (newVal) {
    var validated = false;
    // Run your custom validation checks
    if(newVal)
    {
        validated = true;
    }
    return validated;
};

$scope.$watch('formData.license', function (newVal) {
    $scope.licenseValidated = validateLicense(newVal);
});
```

Ok, that works. But in my second step I have multiple fields like this:

```
<div class="profile">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="formData.profile.name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="street">Street</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" ng-model="formData.profile.street">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode" ng-model="formData.profile.zipcode">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <a ng-click="next(1)" ui-sref="form.license" class="btn btn-block btn-previous col-xs-3">
                VORIGE
            </a>
            <a ng-click="next(2)" ui-sref="form.appointment" class="btn btn-block btn-next col-xs-3">
                Volgende
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to create for every one of them a $scope.watch? And do I need to add them to ng-disabled of my button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply disable the next button if any of the validation steps doesn't pass.

Something like:

```
// Inside your controller.
// Don't overload the scope.
// Only assign what will be needed through your HTML or other AngularJS Scopes
var validateLicense = function (newVal) {
    // If you are only checking for content to be entered
    return (newVal !== '' && newVal !== undefined);
};
var validateInfo = function (newVal) {
    if (newVal.length > 0) {
        // Check to make sure that all of them have content
        for (var i = 0, l = newVal.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (newVal[i] === undefined || newVal[i] === '') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // We didn't find invalid data, let's move on
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

var validateDate = function (newVal) {
    var validated = false;
    // Run your custom validation checks
    return validated;
}

// Initialize the disabled "Next" buttons
$scope.licenseValidated = false;
$scope.infoValidated = false;

// Watch a single item in a form, if filled in we will let them proceed
$scope.$watch('formData.license', function (newVal) {
    $scope.licenseValidated = validateLicense(newVal);
});

// Watch a multiple items in a form, if ALL are filled in we will let them proceed
// Note that the order in this array is the order the newVal will be,
// So further validation for formData.number would be on newVal[1]
$scope.$watchGroup(['formData.name', 'formData.number', 'formData.address'], function (newVal) {
    $scope.infoValidated = validateInfo(newVal);
});
```

form-license.html add the `ng-disabled` attribute on your next button:

```
<a ng-click="next(1, appointmentform)" ui-sref="form.profile" class="btn btn-next btn-block" ng-disabled="!licenseValidated">
    Volgende
</a>
```

form-info.html repeat above steps

```
<a ng-click="next(1, appointmentform)" ui-sref="form.profile" class="btn btn-next btn-block" ng-disabled="!infoValidated">
    Volgende
</a>
```

And so on...

<kbd>[See this Fiddle for Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kqeo1pcm/4/)</kbd>

Comment: And what do you mean with custom validation checks? For example, required. Just check: if(newVal){ validated = true; } . Like this?

Comment: No, `newVal` is whatever the input is, it isn't the form object so there isn't a `newVal.$valid` check. What I mean is, let's say that you want to make sure that the license is at least 20 characters and contains letters and numbers or something. You could do a regex test against that. Angular's `.$valid` only checks very limited criteria. Like if there is input or it's empty, etc.

Comment: You could have a div underneath the next button `<div class="errorMsg" ng-show="!licenseValidated">{{  error.msg }}</div>` and if the validation fails than assign `$scope.error.msg` equal to whatever you want the user to see.

Comment: Could you take a look at my topic? I just have one little question. Updated my topic.

Comment: @nielsv check out this fiddle to see different options and how to approach multiple input elements https://jsfiddle.net/kqeo1pcm/3/

Comment: Thanks! You're my hero of the day!

Comment: @nielsv Glad I could help. Best of luck to you!

Comment: I personally wouldn't go with the disabled button approach as it is not very user friendly. For reasons see here http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/76306/87632

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options available to you depending on how you want to approach it.

To start, you should use `ng-form` for each of the 3 form steps. This will allow you to validate each individually without having to worry about the other sections.

So as an example your first form step might turn into:

```
<ng-form name="LicenseForm">
    <label>Nummerplaat ingeven</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="license" ng-model="formData.license">

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
            <a ng-click="next(1, LicenseForm)" ui-sref="form.profile" class="btn btn-next btn-block">
                Volgende
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

This gives you access to the form validation properties for just this step. At this point you can update your controller to use `.$invalid` or `.$valid` on the form object that is now being passed in the `next` submit button, meaning you can now do something like:

```
$scope.next = function(step, form) {
    if (form.$invalid) {
        console.log('Form is invalid!');
        return;
    }
    // move to next section
    ...
};
```