# Logic for the Next button for the questionnaire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am beginner in AngularJS and facing some issues. I am trying to make a questionnaire having 1 question on each page. On every Next button data is save in the database. I am trying to make a Next button logic but couldn't get an idea how to make a generic NEXT button logic which enables next field using ng-show, disables the current one and lastly store the current value of field in database. Can someone help to make a logic for Next button that will enable next div show on next page and also store data in Database?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <section class="col-md-12 well">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-key"></i>User Creation</h1>
        <hr />
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Basic Information </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="firstNameDiv">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.firstName" required />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group" ng-show="middleNameDiv">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" ng-model="user.middleName" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group" ng-show="lastNameDiv">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="user.lastName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="genderDiv">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="male" ng-model="user.gender">Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="female" ng-model="user.gender" disabled>Female</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="ageDiv">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="age">Age</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" ng-model="user.age" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Back</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" ng-click="next()"></i> Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Javascript: UserController.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope,   $routeParams, $sanitize, $location, UserSrv) {
    // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
    $scope.loading = false;

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.firstNameDiv = true;
        $scope.middleNameDiv = false;
        $scope.lastNameDiv = false;
        $scope.genderDiv = false;
        $scope.ageDiv = false;
    };
    // runs once per controller instantiation
    $scope.init();

    $scope.next = function() {
        $scope.firstNameDiv = false;
        // Call User service with firstNameDiv value.
        UserSrv.saveData();
        $scope.middleNameDiv = true;
        // Logic to enable next field and save the current field value 
        // ???
    }
});
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a **multi-step form** (also known as **Wizard**).
For this purpose why not using [Angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as suggested in this post:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

which is a tutorial guiding to create a Wizard and has a working example (a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview)).

There are also other **Angular modules** which aim to do the same:

- https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form  ([demos and docs here](http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/angular-multi-step-form/#/home))
- https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard ([demo here](http://mgonto.github.io/angular-wizard/))

And in conclusion another **tutorial** with working demo:

- http://code.realcrowd.com/the-wonderful-wizard-of-angularjs/

But if you "*google*" for "multi-step form angular" you can find some more examples.

Also on *StackOverflow* you can find suggestions on how to create a multi-step form (for example see [AngularJS multi-step form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765974/angularjs-multi-step-form-validation)).

Answer (score 3):

You could save your showDiv booleans in an array, and keep the corresponding index in memory. So something like this:

```
$scope.currentState = 0;

//ordered representation of possible states
$scope.stateArray = [true, false, false, false, false];

$scope.next = function(){

  //on to the next showDiv
  currentState++;

  stateArray.forEach(function(index, state){

    //hide everything else.
    if(index != currentState){
      state = false;
    }
    else{
      state = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your html, do `ng-show="stateArray[currentState]"`

You'll inadvertently gain a "previous" function from this if you choose by decrementing the currentState instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would create three custom directives that can be used to build a multi-part form:

1. `myMultiPartForm` directive would wrap the form and keep track of which part is visible
2. `myFormPart` directive would be used multiple times as a wrapper for each form section
3. `myFormPartSubmit` would be used on the submit button in each form part, to advance to the next part

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/wb4jkqLa/)

### Example

**index.html**

In this file, I am using `MyViewController` as the view, which will expose a `part` variable for keeping track of which form part is currently being displayed, as well as a `save` method that each form part can call when it is submitted.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyViewController as view">
  <my-multi-part-form part="{{view.part}}">
    <my-form-part on-submit="view.save(data)">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="formPart.data.name">
      </label>
      <button my-form-part-submit>
        Next
      </button>
    </my-form-part>
    <my-form-part on-submit="view.save(data)">
      <label>
        Age:
        <input type="number" ng-model="formPart.data.age">
      </label>
      <button my-form-part-submit>
        Next
      </button>
    </my-form-part>
    <my-form-part on-submit="view.save(data)">
      <label>
        Gender:
        <select ng-model="formPart.data.gender">
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <button my-form-part-submit>
        Done
      </button>
    </my-form-part>
  </my-multi-part-form>
  <div ng-if="view.part > 2">
    Complete!
  </div>
</div>
```

**view.controller.js**

The view controller initializes the `part` variable at zero, which is the index of the first form part (form parts are stored in an array, in `MultiPartFormController`).

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyViewController', MyViewController)
;

function MyViewController($http) {
  var view = this;
  view.part = 0;
  view.save = function(data) {
    $http({
      method : 'POST',
      url    : 'https://example.com',
      data   : data
    }).then(function success(res) {
      /** handle success **/
      view.part++;
    }).catch(function error(err) {
      /** handle error **/
    });
  };
}
```

**multi-part-form.directive.js**

Here, I define the `myMultiPartForm` directive and observe the `part` attribute, which is the interpolated value of `view.part`. Whenever that value changes (i.e. on success after `view.save` is called), it will hide all form parts except the one that `view.part` now references.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myMultiPartForm', myMultiPartFormDirective)
  .controller('MultiPartFormController', MultiPartFormController)
;

function myMultiPartFormDirective() {
  return {
    controller  : 'MultiPartFormController',
    controllerAs: 'multiPartForm',
    link        : postLink
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, multiPartForm) {
    iAttrs.$observe('part', function (newValue) {
      angular.forEach(multiPartForm.parts, function (part, index) {
        if (index == newValue) part.show();
        else part.hide();
      });
    });
  }
}

function MultiPartFormController() {
  var multiPartForm = this;
  multiPartForm.parts = [];
}
```

**form-part.directive.js**

Here's where it gets cool. Each `myFormPart` directive adds `show` and `hide` methods to its controller during the post-link phase, then adds a reference to its controller to the `parts` array of the `myMultiPartForm` controller. This enables `myMultiPartForm` to manipulate the DOM element of each `myFormPart` without needing to traverse the DOM tree using jQuery or jqLite.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myFormPart', myFormPartDirective)
  .controller('FormPartController', FormPartController)
;

function myFormPartDirective() {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      onSubmit: '&'
    },
    controller      : 'FormPartController',
    controllerAs    : 'formPart',
    link            : postLink,
    require         : ['myFormPart', '^myMultiPartForm'],
    scope           : true,
    template        : '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    transclude      : true
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controllers) {
    var formPart = controllers[0];
    var multiPartForm = controllers[1];
    formPart.hide = function () {
      iElement.css({display: 'none'});
    };
    formPart.show = function () {
      iElement.css({display: 'block'});
    };
    multiPartForm.parts.push(formPart);
  }
}

function FormPartController() {
  var formPart = this;
  formPart.data = {};
}
```

**form-part-submit.directive.js**

Finally, this directive adds a click handler to whatever element it is applied to that will call `myFormPart.onSubmit`, which in this example is always the `view.save` method (but could be a different function for each form part).

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myFormPartSubmit', myFormPartSubmitDirective)
;

function myFormPartSubmitDirective() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: '^myFormPart'
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, formPart) {
    iElement.on('click', function() {
      if (typeof formPart.onSubmit === 'function') {
        formPart.onSubmit({data: formPart.data});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

### Order of Operations

To understand how all of this works, you need to understand the order in which things happen. Here is an outline:

1. multiPartForm controller instantiated
2. formPart A controller instantiated
3. formPartSubmit A DOM element linked
4. formPart A DOM element linked
5. formPart B controller instantiated
6. formPartSubmit B DOM element linked
7. formPart B DOM element linked
8. formPart C controller instantiated
9. formPartSubmit C DOM element linked
10. formPart C DOM element linked
11. multiPartForm DOM element linked

The `multiPartForm` controller is instantiated first, but linked last. That means by the time its postLink function is called, its controller has all of the information it needs about each formPart. Then, the `part` value gets interpolated and the first $observe callback is fired.