# How to build ui router nesting where navigation is first state - with multiple "wizards" with 3 steps or more

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-router, nested-routes

I'm trying to build a nested view using AngularJS and UI router. The solution should have multiple steps with different questionares. First step is a menu that leads to different wizards (each with 3 or more steps). Problem is the menu should dissapear once the wizard is initiated.

What i have so far:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

.state("personal-life", {
url:'/personal-life', 
controller:"PersonalCtrl", 
templateUrl: 'views/personal.html'
})

.state("personal-life.step2",{
url:'/step2', 
controller: "PersonalCtrl", 
templateUrl:'views/personal-life/step2.html'
})

.state("personal-life.step2.step3"**,{
url:'/step3', 
controller: "PersonalCtrl", 
templateUrl:'views/personal-life/step3.html'
})

.state("career", {
url:'/career', 
controller:"CareerCtrl", 
templateUrl: 'views/career.html'
})

.state("career.step2",{
url:'/step2', 
controller: "CareerCtrl", 
templateUrl:'views/career/step2.html'
})

.state("career.step2.step3",{
url:'/step3', 
controller: "CareerCtrl", 
templateUrl:'views/career/step3.html'
})

}])
```

The way i handeled views for now:

in index.html i simply added the navigation into the view itself so it dissapears when first step is loaded. Ui-sref is set to load initial state of different "wizards"

```
<div ui-view>
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="personal-life">Personal</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="career">Career</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The file that is loaded after user selects "ui-sref="personal-life" is
personal.html:

```
  <div ui-view>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <h1>Step 1 / 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
    <a ui-sref=".step2" class="small button secondary>Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this point i also nested the content of a first step into ui-view (this allowed me to load the first step automatically and then next steps are loaded within the same area).

Next part of code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
   <h1>Step 2 / 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
     <a ui-sref=".step3" class="small button secondary button-next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is where i have problems.. I'm not able to "target" the third step. Is it problem in how i constructed the whole solution by placing first step content into ui-view or in the ui-sref link for third step ? 
Is there are better way to achieve similar solution within UI router ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: is there any particular reason to do `personal-life.step2.step3`? why don't you just `personal-life.step3`

Comment: It is because i get an error
`Could not resolve '.step3' from state 'personal-life.step2'`
Maybe this is because step3 is within step2 view ?

Comment: change also the `ui-sref` from `.step3` to `personal-life.step3`

Comment: Ahh i see now.. This works thank you very much. 
Could i also get your opinion on this overall solution ? At the end i will need to collect the answers within each $scope and send them via email - do you think I constructed the routing correctly or i might have any issues ?

Comment: You should check out the answers and comments to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34698226/630544

Comment: Thank you. Looking into it.